# favicon.ico for a REST-like web service using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, favicon

I have a REST-like web service that is deployed on Tomcat.  There is no HTML in my servlet response; it's XML.  I'd like to use my own favicon.ico instead of the Tomcat default.

If I place the file at webapps/myWebApp/favicon.ico, it doesn't load.  I still get the Tomcat default.  Going to `http://localhost/myWebApp/favicon.ico` shows that the file is indeed in place.

If I **replace** the file at webapps/ROOT/favicon.ico, then I get my new favicon.  This isn't ideal because I'd like to package the favicon.ico in my war file and ideally wouldn't want other web apps to use my favicon.ico anyways.

Is there a better way to get my new favicon recognized?

For the record, I'm using Tomcat 7 and between each test, I restart Tomcat, clear my browser cache, and restart my browser.

Comment: Well, I'm sure that the browser does some conversion with a built-in XML viewer, but I can do Ctrl-U to view the actual XML.  Real clients won't use a browser at all, but I'd still like the favicon.ico for branding purposes.

Comment: This web service has thousands of consumers.  The favicon will add a touch of branding and will obfuscate the technology (Tomcat) used behind the scenes.

Comment: Do your users actually look at the XML, without any HTML presentation layer (perhaps via in-browser XSLT)?

Comment: I'm sure that they only look at it when doing their integration.  I believe you may be implying that it may not make sense to spend effort customizing the favicon.  I would agree that the benefits are very low, but if it's easy enough to do, I'll do it.  If there is no easy way, I'll forget about it.

Comment: (I've removed some of my comments.) As far as I know favicons are deals with by URL squatting (`/favicon.ico`) or via links in the HTML header (which XML can't handle). To get rid of the Tomcat favicon, you might be able to get rid of the ROOT webapp altogether (if it's not needed).

Comment: Apart from removing the ROOT webapp, Bruno is correct with his assertion about the location of the favicon.ico file.

You must have a ROOT application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how "favicon" works: you either have to specify the URL of the favorite-icon to use (using <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />) or put your favicon.ico file into the root of the server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility

So, since you are serving XML, you only have the one option.